# how can a sourced file inherit trap DEBUG?

Tags: bash, debugging, bash-trap

Running the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

function preexec ()
{
    echo -e "\n-->preexec command: $BASH_COMMAND"
}
trap 'preexec' DEBUG

function testfunc ()
{
    echo "testfunc called $1"
}

testfunc "main"
source "source.sh"

exit 0
```

where source.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

testfunc "source"
```

gives:

```
-->preexec command: testfunc "main"
testfunc called main

-->preexec command: source "source.sh"
testfunc called source

-->preexec command: exit 0
```

which means that every commands inside the sourced file are not trapped by the DEBUG trap.
In fact if I add the line

```
trap 'preexec' DEBUG
```

inside source.sh as second line, everything works as wanted (commands inside source file are trapped too).


How can I make this a default behaviour in order to avoid repeating the above line for any file I need to source?
In other words: is there any chance to tell the sourced file to inherit the DEBUG trap?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved setting in the main file:

```
set -o functrace
```

From BASH man:

> If set, any traps on DEBUG and RETURN are inherited by shell
>   functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell
>   environment. The DEBUG and RETURN traps are normally not inherited in
>   such cases.

Being *'source'* a shell function, they are inherited.